# Parsing dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a javascript library that's capable of parsing dates in the same way that C#'s Datetime.Parse() function does. I'm looking for something that is:

- Reliable: It needs to be suitable for use in a production environment. So no bugs
- Support the European/Australian date format (dd/mm/yyyy). It should possess an option to interpret the first digits as the days part instead of the months part, as is the case in the USA.
- Parse without requiring a format specifier. I want to be able to throw any "reasonable" input at it and expect it to work. E.g. "1/6/2011", "1-6-2011", "7/4/11" (interpret as 2011 as that's the century we're in), "1 March 2011", "1 Oct 2011", "Oct 1 2011", etc
- It should not attempt to guess when given bad input. "45 july 2012" should fail the validation rather than parse as mid-august.

So basically I just need something that makes date parsing on the front end as trivial is it is on the backend using dot.net.

Answer (score 1):

datejs is the best JS library  i have ever used for date manipulation. Check date.js [here](http://www.datejs.com/) . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it meets all of the requirements that you've listed, but a very strong contender is http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this one:

http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/

Good luck!